# php INSERT INTO database variable name

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to use

```
$SomeTable = "SomeTable";
INSERT INTO "' . $SomeTable . '" SET ...
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable SET ...
```

I am unsuccessful. Why am I unable to use a php variable to call a database name?

Comment: You need to wrap table names (and column names) in backticks, not single or double quotes.

Comment: And you should really be using prepared statements rather than just concatenating strings.

Comment: @Chris Sadly you can't use placeholders for table names. This is a massive oversight.

Comment: @tadman Really!? I would have thought it would be the same principle? Wow. Learn something new every day.

Comment: PDO really should do it, but for some reason it's never gained this capability. Data placeholders are always escaped as strings, but table names use a different escaping method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use something like this:

```
$SomeTable = "SomeTable";
$query = 'INSERT INTO `' . $SomeTable . '` SET ... ';
```

Which uses the ` character instead of quotes

Comment: why are the backticks necessary there?

Comment: I believe its to help distinguish it from SQL statements such as WHERE, FROM, etc. I didn't find anything official in my brief google